# Pre defined SPGridView Missing Filter Icon

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spgridview

I have an SPGridView and ObjectDataSource which are all pre defined in the ascx, bu the grid are just populated by the code behind via the object data source code. The grid view is inside an update panel.

I am encountering an issue where the filter icon is missing.

Is it possible to insert this even though I don't create the spgridview columns dynamically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue, i have found a way to do it by defining the rowdatabound of my spgridview on pre-render of my control.

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d7204aa-74a5-4bec-bb8c-db0c6cb79c6b/spgridview-filtering-missing-filter-icon?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) forum link.